# What is the best way to run HTTPS for drupal commerce

Tags: commerce, ssl

I have seen the module [Secure Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages), and also found [Custom SSL redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_ssl_redirect) and read all the issues related to this and Commerce, but most seem out dated.

Can anyone say as of this point what is the best way to run the site on http and the checkout (anonymous users) with https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over your hosting, the easiest is to serve everything on https, this will make the whole setup easy and if used in combination with [SPDY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) - and [PFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) - you get both speed and [SEO](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.be/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal_6.html) improvements.

Comment: What about SEO penalties for redirects, Is google smart enough to know its the same site? Already the site will have many redirects though (re-build site launch)

Comment: AFAIK redirects from http to https are allowed, google prefers all sites running on https.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's 'best', it depends what you mean by that.

If you're just looking for a working solution, the dev version of Secure Pages along with the core patches it recommends works great.

Best thing you can do is install the various options you've identified, do your testing as normal, and ask a more specific question if the modules do something you don't expect.